# Cannot see TFS team project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-project, tfs-security

We are using TFS 2013. We have got 4 team projects in the TFS and I have been added as a member to all of these team projects. When I try to access the TFS server via VS 2013 -> Add server -> Select Team Projects, I can only see the 3 team projects. Why is this happening that I cannot see the 4th project??

In web console -> Manage users I have confirmed that I have got the access to the team project which doesn't show up in the Visual Studio -> Select team projects.

Comment: If you go to the Web Access can you access the work items in that project?

Comment: The web access to work items shows the following:
This feature cannot be used until you configure it for this team project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have combination of TFS projects as well as Git (integrated to TFS) then sometimes that can cause this problem. If you remove the Git repositories then your TFS projects will start showing up again.